# What is the best way to add "Tweet" button to a C++ application for Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I want to add a "Tweet" button to a C++ application without use of heavy libraries and frameworks. The application is portable and runs on Android and Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your setup. If you have implemented a native part of an Android app you can still write some java UI code and call your c++ code from there. 
If you want to have a full portable solution though I would render simple button with help of OpenGL.

**UPDATE** Oh I see what you meant, so this is actually quite simple. For Android many people use [Twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) which is not that "heavy". You can also implement API calls on your own, see the official [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs). Besides, there are a couple of more possibilities on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782743/twitter-integration-on-android-app) with links to some tutorials.

As for portability, it gets a bit trickier. I would stick with twitter API and implement HTTP calls directly. The quickest way to get it done in a portable way is to write a thin wrapper around the socket calls as someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472175/portable-lightweight-c-sockets-wrapper) suggested.

You could also use [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) or [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) library, but I have not checked them personally. The latter is available for windows and has recently been ported to Android.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is not about rendering, this is all about making action after the button is pressed: how to submit something to twitter.

Comment: Ok, thats good for Java, but how about portability? I want my button to work in Windows and stick to C++ there.