# Sockets: any library or wrapper for "fd" and "select" operations?

Tags: c, sockets, networking

Is there any C wrapper or library for operations on raw sockets (`fd`, [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select), ...)? No rocket science, just a readable, nice wrapper around `FD_SET` etc.

[boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) is for C++, so useless here.

I know [Beej's guide to network programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) and how to operate on sockets, I look for the wrapper before I start wrapping it myself

**Related**

- [Portable lightweight C++ sockets wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472175/portable-lightweight-c-sockets-wrapper)

Comment: See e.g. [libevent](http://libevent.org/) for the `select` bit.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: that's exactly what I need. Post it as an answer and I will close the thread, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, just use appropriate [syscalls](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) wrapped by the standard GNU libc library.
Use [socket(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/socket.2.html) to get the fd on the raw socket, then use other syscalls like [recv(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/recv.2.html), [poll(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html) etc etc.

You probably need root privilege to use raw sockets.

You should prefer `poll(2)` to [select(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) which is becoming obsolete. (Read more about the [C10K](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) issue).

See also [socket(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/socket.7.html) & [packet(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/packet.7.html) man pages.

Comment: Well, that is want I wanted to wrap a bit - especially `FD_` operations and `select`

Comment: Use `poll(2)` or `ppoll(2)` not `select(2)` which is obsolete (only able to handle file descriptors less than 256 or 1024).

Comment: The notes of http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html and the `FD_SETSIZE` constant in system headers. You really should forget about `select(2)` and use `poll(2)`

Answer (score 1):

take a look at libdnet. Details: http://libdnet.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at rn by Dan Kegel (the c10k guy): http://www.kegel.com/rn/. It has plain-old-c interface around multiple select-like syscalls such as poll/epoll/sigio. There are significant performance difference between them at high fd counts and the best interfaces (epoll/kqueue) are non-portable.

The rn api is epoll-ish: you only add/remove individual fds instead of passing the whole list around like for select. Good old select with a FD_SET is limited at compile time to a number of sockets and copies the entire list from user-to-kernel space at every call. Using epoll you have separate syscalls to add/remove individual FDs which are fast even when you are waiting on 100K idle sockets.

All modern linux systems should support epoll. If you don't care about portability you can use it directly.